# Nonconsecutive $timeoutId using $timeout inside a promise chain (AngularJS 1.x)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, timeout, angular-promise

I have a very simple controller which runs three timeouts in series, one after the other in a promise chain. I've used a function `timeoutHelper` which creates the timeouts and logs them to the console.

```
.controller('ctrl', function($timeout) { 
    function timeoutHelper(time) {
      var t = $timeout(time);
      console.log(t);
      return t;
    }

    timeoutHelper(500)
    .then(function(){
      return timeoutHelper(500);
    })
    .then(function(){
      return timeoutHelper(500);
    });
  })
```

It works fine and each `$timeout` is logged to the console after 500ms, but the `$$timeoutId` are non consecutive. The output to the console looks like this

```
Promise {$$state: Object, $$timeoutId: 1}
Promise {$$state: Object, $$timeoutId: 3}
Promise {$$state: Object, $$timeoutId: 5}
```

Creating the `$timeout` outside of a promise chain results in consecutive `$$timeoutId` as expected. Why is this happening?

The reason this is an issue is because I'm having a problem flushing the `$timeout` in my Unit tests. After calling `$timeout.flush(500)` three times I get an exception thrown when calling `$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks`. This example is just a simplified version of what I'm doing in my application but it demonstrates the same issue.

Here is a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DBt95iz81frftH34SbWy) of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of invoking the functions inside the `.then` methods. pass the timeou functions as arguments to the `.then` method

```
angular.module('timeoutApp', [])

      .controller('ctrl', function($timeout, $q, $scope) {

        function timeoutHelper(time) {
          var t = $timeout(time);
          console.log(t);
          return t;
        }

        timeoutHelper(500)
        .then(timeoutHelper(500))
        .then(timeoutHelper(500));


      })
```

result

`Promise {$$state: Object, $$timeoutId: 1}`

`Promise {$$state: Object, $$timeoutId: 2}`

`Promise {$$state: Object, $$timeoutId: 3}`

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/tIIoBN797lWqBFeqDYdo?p=preview)